# Access the items from a dataframe and create a new one using same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using this `dataframe` (`df1`) :

```
df1 =  pd.read_csv('City_Zhvi_AllHomes.csv',header=None)
```

Its content contains columns written in the format Year-Months(1-12). Now I have to create a new `dataframe` that contains data from `Df1` divided in 4 quarters. Here's what I have done:

```
Month = ['00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12']

Year=['00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16']


for i in range(0,15):

      for j in range(0,12):

          newdf = pd.DataFrame[df1.loc[2,'20'+Year[i]+'-'+Month[j+1]] + df1.loc[2,'20'+Year[i]+'-'+Month[j+2]]+ df1.loc[2,'20'+Year[i]+'-'+Month[j+3]],columns = ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'] ] 
          j = j + 3


print newdf .
```

I have done this specifically for second row however I need to perform this for entire dataset

Now I get this error:

> 'type' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Here's the sample data :

```
0             CountyName  SizeRank  2000-01  2000-02  2000-03  2000-04   
1                 Queens         1      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
2            Los Angeles         2   204400   207000   209800   212300   
3                   Cook         3   136800   138300   140100   141900   
4           Philadelphia         4    52700    53100    53200    53400
```

newdf should contain :

```
Q1                      
(204400+207000+209800)
```

Similarly Q2,Q3,Q4

How do I proceed?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html - there is built-in functionality for this.

Comment: Can you add to your question sample data - 5-6 rows and desired output? Also maybe help [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by columns `axis=1` with aggregate `sum`, but first is necessary [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) of columns `CountyName` and `SizeRank` and then convert column names first  [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_datetime.html) and then [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html):

```
#remove header=None for first row in csv as columns
df =  pd.read_csv('City_Zhvi_AllHomes.csv')

df = df.set_index(['CountyName','SizeRank'])
#with real data set index of all not dates columns
#df = df.set_index(['RegionID', 'RegionName', 'State', 'Metro', 'CountyName', 'SizeRank'])
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).to_period('M')
print (df)
                        2000-01   2000-02   2000-03   2000-04
CountyName   SizeRank                                        
Queens       1              NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
Los Angeles  2         204400.0  207000.0  209800.0  212300.0
Cook         3         136800.0  138300.0  140100.0  141900.0
Philadelphia 4          52700.0   53100.0   53200.0   53400.0

print (df.columns)
PeriodIndex(['2000-01', '2000-02', '2000-03', '2000-04'], dtype='period[M]', freq='M')

df = df.resample('Q', axis=1).sum()
print (df)
                         2000Q1    2000Q2
CountyName   SizeRank                    
Queens       1              NaN       NaN
Los Angeles  2         621200.0  212300.0
Cook         3         415200.0  141900.0
Philadelphia 4         159000.0   53400.0
```

Comment: Getting this error : 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_period'

Comment: This is the output or columns :([u'RegionID', u'RegionName', u'State', u'Metro', u'CountyName', u'SizeRank', u'2000-01', u'2000-02', u'2000-03', u'2000-04', u'2000-05', u'2000-06', u'2000-07', u'2000-08', u'2000-09', u'2000-10', u'2000-11', u'2000-12', u'2001-01', u'2001-02', u'2001-03', u'2001-04', u'2001-05', u'2001-06', u'2001-07', u'2001-08', u'2001-09', u'2001-10', u'2001-11', u'2001-12', u'2002-01', u'2002-02', u'2002-03', u'2002-04', u'2002-05', u'2002-06', u'2002-07', u'2002-08', u'2002-09', u'2002-10', u'2002-11', u'2002-12',  ...], dtype='object')

Comment: Ok, then need `set_index` of all columns which are not dates like `df = df.set_index(['RegionID', 'RegionName', 'State', 'Metro', 'CountyName', 'SizeRank'])`

Comment: so instead `df = df.set_index(['CountyName','SizeRank'])` need `df = df.set_index(['RegionID', 'RegionName', 'State', 'Metro', 'CountyName', 'SizeRank'])`

Comment: Yeah . Got it . Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133869/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-jezrael).